# Perhaps not understanding the OS X permissions model

Tags: mac-osx, permissions

Trying to set up a complex config for the bundled Httpd on MacOSX 10.6.

In the log for the httpd:

```
[Wed Mar 23 09:18:07 2011] [error] [client ::1] (13)Permission denied: mod_rewrite: can't access text RewriteMap file /Users/benson/x/btweb/web_2_0/resources/metadata/us-redirct-map.txt

ls -l /Users/benson/x/btweb/web_2_0/resources/metadata/us-redirct-map.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 benson  staff  74542 Mar 22 20:05 /Users/benson/x/btweb/web_2_0/resources/metadata/us-redirct-map.txt
```

So, the mode is 0777, everyone has access, but the httpd gets 'Permission denied'.

Using the finder and GetInfo I see that everyone has full access. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

httpd probably doesn't have read and/or execute permissions on the directories leading to it, preventing it from getting to the file in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Apache expects to be an owner/group owner of the folders which should access. It maintains it own permission model based on realms.

Answer (score 0):

You should at least set the owner of all your web files to "www" (and maybe the group as well)  with rwx privileges.