# Perhaps not understanding the OS/X ACL model

Tags: mac-osx, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Perhaps not understanding the OS X permissions model](https://serverfault.com/questions/250805/perhaps-not-understanding-the-os-x-permissions-model)

In the log for the httpd:

```
[Wed Mar 23 09:18:07 2011] [error] [client ::1] (13)Permission denied: mod_rewrite: can't access text RewriteMap file /Users/benson/x/btweb/web_2_0/resources/metadata/us-redirct-map.txt

ls -l /Users/benson/x/btweb/web_2_0/resources/metadata/us-redirct-map.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 benson  staff  74542 Mar 22 20:05 /Users/benson/x/btweb/web_2_0/resources/metadata/us-redirct-map.txt
```

So, the mode is 0777, everyone has access, but the httpd gets 'Permission denied'.

Using the finder and GetInfo I see that everyone has full access. What am I missing?

Comment: This question is more suited for ServerFault. Voting to close.

Comment: It's completely osx specific, but have it your way. Is there a migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably caused by the directories further up the tree (namely /Users/benson/) not having the execute bit set.

Andrew